# How to get property value from dynamic model in MVC razor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

View:

```
@model  dynamic

<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select a Country <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       @foreach (dynamic m in Model)
       {
          <li><a href="#">"@m.EmployeeName"</a></li>
       }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
             var Employees = Connections.SaleBranch.SqlConn.Query("SELECT EmployeeName,EmployeeID FROM dbo.udft_Employee(@RunDate) WHERE OfficerEmployeeID=@OfficerEmployeeID",
            new { OfficerEmployeeID = 78273, RunDate = DateTime.Now.GetPersianDate() },
            commandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();
            var EmployeesList = Employees.Select(x => new { EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName, EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID }).ToList();

            return View("Point/Index", EmployeesList);
        }
```

The object `m` shows 2 properties(EmployeeName,EmployeeID).

[image]

But can't fetch `m.EmployeeName` value

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try get desired value via reflection:

```
@foreach (dynamic m in Model)
{    
    var EmployeeName = m.GetType().GetProperty("EmployeeName").GetValue(m);
    <li><a href="#">"@EmployeeName"</a></li>    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the objects in employeesList are not dynamic but are anonymous objects. Anonymous can't be used outside the scope they are created in.

A dynamic view model is not a good idea, but if you insist, you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead I would make a strongly typed model for the view.